# Trying to build UE 4.25 fork/SpatialOS on Ubuntu 20 Linux

Tags: linux, spatial, unreal-engine4

I am trying to build this fork of Unreal Engine 4.25 on Ubuntu 20 Linux: https://github.com/improbableio/UnrealEngine

**$ ./Setup.sh**

works fine, all success!

**$ ./GenerateProjectFiles.sh**

here I get many warnings like the following:

> Attempting to set up UE4 pretty printers for gdb (existing UE4Printers.py, if any, will be
> overwritten)… updated UE4Printers.py found necessary entries in ~/.gdbinit file, not changing it.

> Setting up Unreal Engine 4 project files… Fixing inconsistent case in filenames.

> Setting up Mono Generating data for project indexing… 0%

> Wrong build env! WARNING: Exception while generating include data for UE4Editor: Unable to instantiate module ‘UVAtlas’:
> Wrong build env! (referenced via Target → ProxyLODMeshReduction.Build.cs) Generating data for project indexing… 100% Generating data for project indexing… 0%Wrong build env! … … …

> Writing project files… 100%

**$ make**

after many successful builds the process stops with this message here:

> Building UE4Editor…

> Using ‘git status’ to determine working set for adaptive non-unity build (/mnt/3091fd7d-024b-4559-a6ee-07633a74e28a/UnrealEngineSpatialOS).

> Creating makefile for UE4Editor (no existing makefile)

> Wrong build env!

> ERROR: Unable to instantiate module ‘UVAtlas’: Wrong build env!
> (referenced via Target → ProxyLODMeshReduction.Build.cs)

Would love to work under Linux! I hope you guys can help me!